# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'height' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I keep getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'height' of undefined. Please help! There are multiple elements with this class name but when the user clicks on it i want just the one they clicked on to change height

```
jQuery('.joke').click(function(){
        var joke = jQuery('.joke');
        joke.style.height = '400px';
    });
```

Comment: _“I want just the one they clicked on to change height”_ — then use `$(this)` or simply `this`, not `joke`.

Answer (score 3):

Do this instead.

```
jQuery('.joke').click(function(){
    $(this).css('height','400px');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `this` instead of `jQuery('.joke')`, `this` refers to dom object

```
jQuery('.joke').click(function(){
    var joke = this;
    joke.style.height = '400px';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using jQuery you could do this:

```
jQuery('.joke').click(function(){
    $(this).css("height", "400px");
});
```

In your code `joke` is the jQuery object, and it doesn't have the `style` property. And you should use `this` beacuse otherwise you are refering to all the elements that has the "joke" class.